# Does not changes element ui-switch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my problem is that when change model not change position element ui-switch

if use just checkbox then all work

my html

```
<input type="checkbox" data-group="{{ roomPerson.person.transfer.is_group }}"
   ng-disabled="!isEdit()"
   class="js-switch"
   ng-change="toggleTransfer(roomPerson)"
   ng-model="roomPerson.person.transfer.isIncluded"
   ui-switch="{color: '#3aa99e',size:'small'}"/>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: please could you provide plunker of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you get your `ui-switch` example from?
It should be added using the `switch` directive.

```js
angular.module('test', ['uiSwitch']).controller('Test', Test);
function Test($scope) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/xpepermint/angular-ui-switch/master/angular-ui-switch.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/xpepermint/angular-ui-switch/master/angular-ui-switch.min.css"/>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <input type="checkbox"
     ng-model="isChecked"/>

  <switch ng-model="isChecked"/>
</div>
```